# How to count the number of related entities over two m2m relations to the same Model in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Given roughly these two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()


class Resource(models.Model):

    people_contributing = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, 
        related_name='resouces_contributing_to'
    )

    people_involved = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, 
        related_name='resources_involved_in'
    )
```

For all persons I want to get the count of resources he/she is either contributing to **OR** involved in.

I tried the following:

```
resources = Resource.objects.all()

participations = Person.objects.filter(
    Q(resources_contributing_to__in=resources) |
    Q(resources_involved_in__in=resources)
).values(
    # group results by person
    'pk'
).annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).values_list(
    'pk',
    'name',
    'count'
).order_by('-count')

print(participations)
```

This gives me a list of tuples like this:

```
[
    # (id, name, count)
    (1, 'John Doe', 12),
    (2, 'Jane Doe', 5),
    (3, 'Donald Trump', 3),
]
```

However if a person is **both contributing and involved** the resource **will be counted twice** because the resource will be joined twice to the person table. What I want is the resource to be counted only once if it is present in both relationships.

**How do I have to change my queryset to prevent this?**

I am using postgresql and Django 1.11.

Comment: Naive question: did you try to use `distinct`?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help because using `distinct(*fields)`together with `annotate()` gives an error that it isn't implemented. And also there is no field that i could give to `distinct()` because i want to count the number of duplicate rows for a persons `pk`. It has to be distinct by `resouce_id` if you want so but i can't figure out how to achive that.

Comment: `distinct` is also an argument you can give to `Count`. Did you try it ?

Comment: @albar Yes but that is obviously not what I want because that would lead to always getting a count of 1 if the person is participating in any resource.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I did not really understand the problem.

Comment: @albar I want to count the number of resources that are related to each person over two different many2many relations.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking. On one hand you say you want to filter your result with `people_contribution XOR people_involved` which means not counting people in both sets at all. On the other hand you say " if a person is **both** contributing and involved the resource will be counted **twice**" as if you wanted them to be counted **once**, in which case using `distinct()` should work.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard You are right. I mixed that up in my mind. What i want is every resource to be counted once if it's present in both relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting entries that are appearing in either of relations can be achieved by counting entries from 1st relation + counting entries from 2nd relation - counting entries from both relations. That can be achieved in Django by this queryset:

```
participations = Person.objects.filter(
    Q(resources_contributing_to__in=resources) |
    Q(resources_involved_in__in=resources)
).annotate(
    count=Count('resouces_contributing_to__id', distinct=True) + Count('resources_involved_in__id', distinct=True) - Count(Case(When(resources_involved_in__id=F('resouces_contributing_to__id'), then='resources_involved_in__id')), distinct=True),
).values_list(
    'pk',
    'name',
    'count'
).order_by('-count')
```

Comment: Yes that is it. Thank you very much sir. But will get very ugly if you have more than two relations because you have to discount all combinations? :)

Comment: One last question. Do you it consider it a better design to only have a single relation with a custom intermediate model that has an extra field that defines the type of relationship?